# foldTree step-by-step evaluation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scope, closures, evaluation

Assuming these definitions of `foldTree`, a `Tree` and a function `f`:

```hs
foldTree : (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f = go
    where
        go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)

tree :: Tree String
tree = Node
      "Alpha"
      [ Node "Beta" [Node "Epsilon" [], Node "Zeta" [], Node "Eta" []]
      , Node "Gamma" [Node "Theta" []]
      , Node "Delta" [Node "Iota" [], Node "Kappa" [], Node "Lambda" []]
      ]

f x xs = [x] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs))
```

I will try to evaluate `foldTree f tree`:

```hs
  foldTree f tree
= go (Node "Alpha" [ Node "Beta" [Node "Epsilon" [], Node "Zeta" [], Node "Eta" []], Node "Gamma" [Node "Theta" []], Node "Delta" [Node "Iota" [], Node "Kappa" [], Node "Lambda" []]]
= f "Alpha" (map go [...])
...
```

At this point, my question is: how does equational reasoning work with closures ? The definition of `go` has `f`; however, that is certainly not between its parameters. Is there some trick that allows the insertion of that definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, a definition is allowed to refer to any name which is *in scope*.

*"Closures"* is a concept much more relevant in the presence of mutation. In Haskell where there's none, a concept of *"scope"* is enough.

`go`'s definition is nested inside that of `foldTree`, so has access to its parameter `f`. In other words, inside `go`'s definition, `f` is in scope.

The definition can be re-written as

```
{-
foldTree f t = go t
    where
         go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
-}
foldTree f t =
   let { go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) } 
   in go t
```

and any call `foldTree f1 t1` is evaluated as

```
> foldTree f1 t1 
=>
  let { f=f1; t=t1 }
  in
    let { go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) } 
    in go t
=>
  ....
```

and these are simple nested `let`s, so the inner one has access to every name defined by the outer one.

To easier see what's going on, try evaluating it first with a simpler example data, like `Node "Alpha" []`, `Node "Alpha" [Node "Beta" []]`, etc.

---

For example, with

```
f0 x xs = [x] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs))
```

the evaluation for `Node "Alpha" []` proceeds as

```
> foldTree f0 (Node "Alpha" []) 
=>
  let { f=f0; t=Node "Alpha" [] }
  in
    let { go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) } 
    in go t
=>
  let { f x xs = [x] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs))
      ; go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) 
      } 
  in go (Node "Alpha" [])
=>
  let { f x xs = [x] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs))
      ; go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) 
      ; (Node x1 ts1) = (Node "Alpha" [])
      } 
  in f x1 (map go ts1)
=>
  let { f x xs = [x] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs))
      ; go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) 
      ; x1 = "Alpha"
      ; ts1 = []
      ; xs1 = map go ts1
      } 
  in [x1] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat xs1))
=>
  ["Alpha"] <> (map ('\t' :) (concat []))
=>
  ["Alpha"] <> (map ('\t' :) [])
=>
  ["Alpha"] <> []
=>
  ["Alpha"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Will Ness !! One question: in the first block of code, you have a `where` clause and a `let` expression and I can't compile it. Is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: Great. Now it works perfectly. About the second block of code, could you tell me how do you replace the definition using `let`? There are many `in` keywords, there. Is there a trick to understanding it ?

Comment: each `let` has only one `in` coming with it, the one which is immediately after it. imagine the inner `let...in...` enclosed in parentheses: `let { f=f1; t=t1 }
  in
    ( let { go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) } 
    in ( go t ) )`. though of course these parens are not necessary, the code is parsed like that anyway.

Comment: I see where the inner `let` comes from. However, I can't see where the outermost `let` comes from. You definition of `foldTree` doesn't include it. Could you explain ?

Comment: I think I am starting to understand ! Thank you again for your help. Could you tell me whether this evaluation is correct ?

Comment: `foldTree' g tree 
= let {f = g; t = tree}
in 
 let go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts) 
  in go t
 )
= let go (Node x ts) = g x (map go ts) 
 in go (Node "Alpha" [])
)
= g "Alpha" (map go [])
= g "Alpha" []`